# Performance: Lots of queries or lots of processing?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Currently I am creating a C# application which has to read a lot of data (over 2,000,000 records) from an existing database and compare it with a lot of other data (also about 2,000,000 records) which do not exist in the database. These comparisons will mostly be `String` comparisons. The amount of data will grow much bigger and therefore I need to know which solution will result in the best performance.

I have already searched the internet and I came up with two solutions;

**Solution 1**

The application will execute a single query (`SELECT column_name FROM table_name`, for example) and store all the data in a `DataTable`. The application will then compare all the stored data with the input, and if there is a comparison it will be written to the database.

*Pros:*

- The query will only be executed once. After that, I can use the stored data multiple times for all incoming records.

*Cons:*

- As the database grows bigger, so will my RAM usage. Currently I have to work with 1GB (I know, tough life) and I'm afraid it won't fit if I'd practically download the whole content of the database in it.
- Processing all the data will take lots and lots of time.

**Solution 2**

The application will execute a specific query for every record, for example

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE value_name = value
```

and will then check is the `DataTable` will have records, something like

```
 if(datatable.Rows.Count>0) { \\etc }
```

If it has records, I can conclude there are matching records and I can write to the database.

*Pros:*

- Probably a lot less usage of RAM since I will only get specific data.
- Processing goes a lot faster.

*Cons:*

- I will have to execute a lot of queries. If you are interested in numbers, it will probably around 5 queries per record. Having 2,000,000 records, that would be 10,000,000 queries.

My question is, what would be the smartest option, given that I have limited RAM?

Any other suggestions are welcome aswell, ofcourse.

Comment: Smartest option == buy more RAM. It's so much cheaper than developer time. Really.

Comment: i say go with "Solution 2", you can find a way to automate the queries.

Comment: You can serialize your _other data_ with XML and pass it to stored procedure which will compare it with _your data_. It is better option than open connections frequently but much better is to buy RAM.

Comment: I disagree. Having better code is better than just buying more RAM in my opinion. Also, I can't buy more RAM since I am not in charge here. Though I have to agree with you that 1GB is somewhat minimal...

Comment: What is the purpose of the comparison? I mean, is there any interest in sending all the rows to your application. If not and therefore you just want the result, I'll suggest to do the comparison database side through stored procedures.
If you need to get the data to the application, just select the columns you need.

Comment: @DionV. you should have both, but most of all the investment should always be worth the result. If you have a slow server, and you can fix it with $100 of hardware, or a week of a developer costing the same per hour - pick the first. Then try to schedule the developer time during a period where they're working on this part of the application anyway.

Comment: @Aymeric I should be more specific there; I do not need to send all rows to my application. However, the rows I need are still in huge amounts. I will edit it.

Comment: If possible load the second set of data into a second table, have sql do the comparison, capture the output straight into the database. Pros: all processing contained in SQL (including the write of result data). Database takes care of memory usage Cons: data import may be slow, greater storage capacity needed

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server available to you, this seems a job directly suited to SQL Server Integration Services. You might consider using that tool instead of building your own. It depends on your exact business needs, but in general data merging like this would be a batch/unattended or tool based operation ?

You might be able to code it to run faster than SSIS, but I'd give it a try just to see if its acceptible to you, and save yourself the cost of the custom development.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll take a look into it tomorrow!